# put text by link style in lightning datatable

Tags: relationships, lightning-datatable, record, lightning-components

I want to put data in lightning datatable by url link style like attached to express the record of relationship.

I tried header type "url", but it showed "http//" in the cells.

How can we put data by url style?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have the column set up incorrectly. You want to use the `fieldName` attribute to hold the url. Then you want to use the `typeAttributes' to hold the text that the user sees.

To read up on `type attributes` and their supported types, see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation)

```
{
  label: "Account Name",
  fieldName: "TheVariableStoringTheLink",
  type: "url",
  sortable: false,
  typeAttributes: {
    label: {
      fieldName: "TheVariableWithTheLabel"
    },

    tooltip: "View the Course"
  }
}
```